# NHibernate Mapping - total records. (Fluent Nhibernate)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have class class1 with some properties and a Mapper class Class1Map which is mapped to table1 in DB.

i need to get top 10 records from table1 along with total number of records in table in a single query using NHibernate.

i added new property in class1 'total records' . How can I map this in class1Map.

Comment: I understand , You want to get count records of table1 ?  It 'll be same for all records . right ?  . Why dont you send new query to count table1 ?

Comment: yes, you are correct. But I want count in same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be performance problem. You will execute subquery for each row.

I dont recommend this . If you want , Add formula to your mappings

```
Id(x => x.Id).Column("id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
Map(x => x.PropA).Column("propA").Nullable();
Map(x => x.TotalRecords).Formula("(select Count(1) from tableA)");
```

I recommend. 
1- get totalRecords of table before execute query
2- Execute your query. 
3- set your property like this:

```
var recordsCount  = Session.Query<TableA>().Count();
var objects = Session.Query<TableA>().Where(yourExpression).Take(10);
objects.Foreach(f=> f.TotalRecords = recordsCount);

return objects;
```

Comment: Thanks..second solution Worked.